# Win32 window gets closed immediately

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I am trying to show a simple win32 window through my application, but the window does not show up. The program is quitting immediately, because a `WM_DESTROY` message is sent through the message pump.
Here is the relevant code:

```
    WNDCLASSEX wClass; //window class structur
    wClass.hInstance = appInstance;
    wClass.lpszClassName = CLASSNAME;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.hIcon = NULL;
    wClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        Debug::getInstance().log("Faild to create Window Class", EDEBUG_LEVEL::E_ERROR);
        //throw some errors
        return;
    }


    windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        CLASSNAME,
        title.c_str(), //real window title
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        position.x, position.y,
        size.x, size.y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        appInstance,
        NULL
        );
    if (windowHandle == NULL)
    {
        Debug::getInstance().log("CreateWindow failed.", EDEBUG_LEVEL::E_ERROR);
    }
```

In this code `appInstance` is the hInstance from the entry `WinMain` function. I have debugged this code, but nothing seems to be going wrong here.

This is my WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // sort through and find what code to run for the message given
    switch (message)
    {
        // this message is read when the window is closed
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
                       // close the application entirely
                       PostQuitMessage(0);
                           return 0;
    } break;
    }

    // Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And my message pump:

```
   while (TRUE) {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

After debugging the `WndProc` function i found that `WM_DESTROY` is getting sent after `WM_CREATE` and 0x0090 (i could not find out what this means).
What am i doing wrong?

Oh forgot to mention. After i create my window this gets also executed:

```
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(windowHandle);
    SetFocus(windowHandle);
```

**EDIT:** After further investigation i found that the problem seems to be caused by calling the window building method from a constructor:

```
Window::Window(HINSTANCE thisInstance, DirectX::XMINT2 size, wstring title, bool enableFullscreen) :
appInstance(thisInstance),
position(0, 0),
size(size),
#ifdef UNICODE
title(title),
#else
title(string(title.begin(), title.end())),
#endif
fullscreen(false)
{
    this->buildWindow();
    if (fullscreen)
        setFullscreenWindowed(true);
}
```

While `this->buildWindow()` is the first code i posted. If i call `buildWindow()` as a public member method from another class it works just fine.
What is wrong here? It is NOT a virtual function. Window does not inherit or implement another class.

Comment: Your message pump is unusual. It usually goes something like this: `while(::GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) { ::TranslateMessage(&Msg); ::DispatchMessage(&Msg); }`. Can you try replacing your existing pump with this and report result?

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff this looks like a typical game-loop message pump; the game processing would be done after the PeekMessage() loop.

Comment: @puelo - is this your entire code? It sounds like maybe the case statement above the WM_DESTROY is missing a break.

Comment: @HerrJoebob: It seems so to me too, but I was not sure. Still, there is nothing I see that could be wrong. Maybe this isn't the actual code and he has `if (msg.message = WM_QUIT)` instead of `if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)` ?

Comment: If `PeekMessage` retrieves other messages in its loop after a `WM_QUIT` then you'll miss it, with the above logic. Also if no messages are in the queue at all then `msg` could be uninitialized when you do the comparison.

Comment: there is no other case statement above the one i posted. and the if statement is like i posted it: `if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)`

Comment: @JonathanPotter after `WM_DESTROY` there is only one more `WM_NCDESTROY` in the WndProc. And there are no other messages besides `WM_QUIT`, after the initial `WM_QUIT`

Comment: Why do you think the constructor is the problem? What's it doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. Sadly since i did not think it was important i did not put this line of code in my question.
The problem was the initialization of the class, because i had no copy constructor defined.

```
Window mainWindow = Window(...)
```

caused the window instance to get Unregistered, since after the object gets copied by the copy constructor the original object gets destructed and i had a method call to `UnregisterClass(..)` in my destructor.

Using:

```
 Window mainWindow(..)
```

fixed the problem.